# How can I use Hugo's param shortcode to access a value in a nested list?

Tags: hugo, hugo-shortcode

I'm trying to use Hugo's baked in `param` shortcode in my markdown file, but I can't figure out what the syntax should be for a nested dict.

For example, if I have the following in my markdown file, I get a `Param "nestedList.[1].value" not found` error

```
---
title: "My Hugo Post"
date: 2023-11-22
nestedList:
  - name: "Nested Item 1"
    value: 10
  - name: "Nested Item 2"
    value: 20
---

I can display the title just fine with: {{< param "title" >}}.

But I can't display the value of the second nested list item ("20") with {{< param "nestedList.[1].value">}}
```

How can I display the value for the second `value` key in the nested dict?

[Hugo's documentation for the `param` shortcode](https://gohugo.io/content-management/shortcodes/#param) isn't helping me, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt if this is possible.

You CAN achieve this by creating a custom shortcode called 'nestedList'. That shortcode can be called like this:

`{{< nestedList 2 >}}`

In that shortcode you can get the second item using:

`{{ (index $.Page.Params.nestedList (.Get 0)).value }}`